# JPA: ORDER BY before GROUP BY in JPARepository

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

This is the mysql query that I've:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT vev.* FROM vital_entry ve 
INNER JOIN vital_entry_values vev ON ve.vital_entry_id=vev.vital_entry_id 
WHERE ve.account_id=146 
ORDER BY date_entered DESC) t1
GROUP BY vital_id ;
```

How do I do this in JPA?? I tried:

```
@Query("SELECT t1 FROM (SELECT ve FROM VitalEntry ve " +
            "INNER JOIN ve.vitalEntryValues vev " +
            "WHERE ve.accountId=:accountId " +
            "ORDER BY ve.dateEntered DESC) t1")
List<VitalEntry> getRecentVitalValues(@Param("accountId") int accountId);
```

But IntelIj shows error `expected identifer, got '('`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gave me the expected result

```
@Query("SELECT new com.v2.model.VitalValue(vev.vitalId, vev.value, max(ve.dateEntered), ve.vitalEntryType, vev.type) FROM VitalEntry ve " +
            "INNER JOIN ve.vitalEntryValues vev " +
            "WHERE ve.accountId=:accountId " +
            "GROUP BY vev.vitalId " +
            "ORDER BY max(ve.dateEntered) DESC")
List<VitalValue> getRecentVitalValues(@Param("accountId") int accountId);
```

Comment: Yes, you can customize the result set with an extral entity.

Answer (score 1):

Use native query instead:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM (SELECT ve.* FROM vital_entry ve INNER JOIN vital_entry_values vev ON ve.vital_entry_id=vev.vital_entry_id WHERE ve.account_id=:accountId ORDER BY date_entered DESC) t1 GROUP BY vital_id", nativeQuery=true)
List<VitalEntry> getRecentVitalValues(@Param("accountId") int accountId);
```

Comment: What about group by?

Comment: Assume vitalId is the field name, `group by ve.vitalId order by ve.dateEntered desc`.

Comment: but that doesn't give me the expected result. I want to order by dateEntered first then group by vitalId, so I'll get the latest value for each vitalId's

Comment: Sounds good, so does reverse the order of `group by` and `order by` work for you?